# Somando valor com Mysql

Tags: mysql

Como faço para somar os valores dos tres selects abaixo:

```
(
SELECT
    (valor1 + valor2 + valor3) AS total SELECT
        SUM(valor) AS valor1
    FROM
        pagamentos
    WHERE
        pagamentos.cliente = '1'
    AND contratosid = '9289'
    AND excluir != '1'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
            SUM(valor) AS valor2
        FROM
            pagcielo
        WHERE
            pagcielo.confirmado = '1'
        AND contratosid = '9289'
        AND excluir != '1'
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                SUM(valor) AS valor3
            FROM
                pagboleto
            WHERE
                pagboleto. STATUS = '1'
            AND contratosid = '9289'
            AND excluir != '1'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um erro na estrutura da sua query.

Em primeiro lugar, opte por deixar as queries conectadas por UNION com a mesma nomenclatura de campos (não é obrigatório, mas facilita):

```
SELECT
  SUM(valor) AS valor
FROM
  pagamentos
WHERE
  pagamentos.cliente = '1'
  AND contratosid = '9289'
  AND excluir != '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  SUM(valor) AS valor
FROM
  pagcielo
WHERE
  pagcielo.confirmado = '1'
  AND contratosid = '9289'
  AND excluir != '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  SUM(valor) AS valor
FROM
  pagboleto
WHERE
  pagboleto. STATUS = '1'
  AND contratosid = '9289'
  AND excluir != '1'
```

Posteriormente trate as queries anteriores como subselect, somando os três campos. A query final ficaria assim:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(VALOR) AS TOTAL
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(valor) AS valor
  FROM
    pagamentos
  WHERE
    pagamentos.cliente = '1'
    AND contratosid = '9289'
    AND excluir != '1'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    SUM(valor) AS valor
  FROM
    pagcielo
  WHERE
    pagcielo.confirmado = '1'
    AND contratosid = '9289'
    AND excluir != '1'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    SUM(valor) AS valor
  FROM
    pagboleto
  WHERE
    pagboleto. STATUS = '1'
    AND contratosid = '9289'
    AND excluir != '1'
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma você consegue somar todos os SELECT juntos

```
select id, sum(valor) from (
    select id,valor from tabela_1 union all
    select id,valor from tabela_2 union all
    select id,valor from tabela_3
) x group by id
```